# No known class method for selector 'archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase

I am working on Firebase realtime database in iOS (Swift 4) and I am receiving the following error:

```
No known class method for selector 'archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error:'
```

In file named `GDTCORStorage.m`. This file is core Objective-C file and is not created by me as I am working in Swift 4. This error happens when I try to import Firebase SDK in POD file like this:

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

I tried:

1. "degenerate" POD files
2. Clean build the project
3. Using Product > Scheme > FirebaseCore & Firebase

None of them worked and I did not find any other solution except for the above 3 mentioned.

Comment: update your Xcode

Comment: Okay, will give it a try.